# Laying a graph over an image for selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an image and would like to lay a graph over it and allow selection of certain pieces of the graph.

For example: I have an image of a human body and would like to partition it into boxes. When you select the box hovering over head, it would return that selection.

I was curious if there was any tool that would help with this. If not, I'll create one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't one specific tool I can think of, but I'll give you a collection of them:

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript

Hope that helps!

Comment: Small hope than. I will just make it by hand. Thanks!